# Unique differentiable structure on homeomorphic manifolds in low dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

When I took the introductory lectures to geometry and topology some years ago our professor mentioned the following result:

> Let $n\in \{1, 2, 3 \}$ and $M, N$ be two $n$-dimensional differentiable manifolds. Then
>   $$ M \text{ and } N \text{ homeomorphic} \Rightarrow  M \text{ and } N \text{ diffeomorphic.} $$

I could not find a reference, where this is acutally proved. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could provide my with a paper (or book) containing this result.

I read in the comment section of [how to prove that every low-dimensional topological manifold has a unique smooth structure up to diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683105/how-to-prove-that-every-low-dimensional-topological-manifold-has-a-unique-smooth) that this should be in Moise's book "Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3", however, I couldn't find such a statement in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Corollary on page 333 of J.Munkres, Obstructions to the smoothing of piecewise-differentiable homeomorphisms, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.
Volume 65, Number 5 (1959), 332-334:

> Every homeomorphism of smooth 3-manifolds can be approximated by diffeomorphisms.

It is probably explained in more details in

J.Munkres, Obstructions to the smoothing of piecewise-differentiable homeomorphisms. Ann. of Math. (2) 72 (1960) 521--554.