# 1D Topological manifold that is not $\mathcal{C}^r$?

Tags: proof-verification, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

The question:

> Find $f$ such that $\{(\mathbb{R},f)\}$ is a one chart atlas for a topological manifold on the set $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{R}$, but not a $C^r$-manifold for $r>0$.

Attempt:

$\mathbb{R}$ is topological space that is Hausdorff, second-countable and locally Euclidean.

**Question: A topological manifold does not really depend on the atlas, right? Just the initial set $\mathcal{M}$ that you given to work with.**

Let
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \quad f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x<0 \\
2x & x\geq 0
\end{cases} $$

$f$ is injective, therefore it generates a chart.

$f$ is bijective, continuous and $f^{-1}$ is continuous so it is homeomorphic.

$f$ is not differentiable so $f$ is not diffeomorphic.

Thus we have a $\mathcal{C}$-manifold.

**Is this correct?**

EDIT:

Let $(\mathbb{R},g)$ be another chart covering $\mathbb{R}$ so that
$\{(\mathbb{R},f),(\mathbb{R},g)\}$ is also an atlas of $\mathbb{R}$. We want $f$ such that for **some** atlas map $g$ 
$$g \circ f^{-1} : f(\mathbb{R})\to g(\mathbb{R})$$ 
is homeomorphic and for but not diffeomorphic.

Let $g$ be the identity map and let

Let
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \quad f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x<0 \\
\frac{x}{2} & x\geq 0
\end{cases} $$
such that
$$(g\circ f^{-1})(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x<0 \\
2x & x\geq 0
\end{cases} $$

$f$ is injective and $g\circ f$ is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic because
the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist.

EDIT II:

Let $(\mathbb{R},g)$ be another chart covering $\mathbb{R}$ so that
$\{(\mathbb{R},f),(U,g)\}$ is also an atlas of $\mathbb{R}$. We want $f$ such that for **any** atlas map $g$ 
$$g \circ f^{-1} : f(\mathbb{R})\to g(\mathbb{R})$$ 
is not diffeomorphic.

So we need to show that for any $g:U\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, with $U$ open and $g$ injective:
$g \circ f^{-1}$ is not bijective or not differentiable.

Comment: You would prove that it is not $C^1$ manifold if you show that you can't extend that atlas to a $C^1$ atlas, i.e. an atlas in which all transition functions are $C^1$. In a one-chart atlas there are no transition functions. Therefore it is trivially $C^1$ so far. But what happens if I add a chart formed by a flat function $g$? Then $g\circ f^{-1}$ can be differentiable just fine.

Comment: Notice that your 'Edit' only shows that the atlas formed by the identity and the one formed by $f$ are not in the same $C^1$ equivalence class. This doesn't mean that the $C^1$ equivalence class of the atlas formed by $f$ doesn't contain other functions.

Comment: Let $g(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$, $g(x)=-e^{-1/x}$ for $x<0$ and $g(0)=0$. Then $g\circ f^{-1}(x)=e^{-2/x}$ for $x>0$, $g\circ f^{-1}(0)=0$, and $g\circ f^{-1}(x)=-e^{-1/x}$ for $x<0$. You can check that $g\circ f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: The thing is that the problem is tricking you. The claim is actually false. If they give a 1-chart atlas, you can get a maximal $C^k$ atlas that contains it for all $k$. [Here is one link with some references](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2388041/553213).

Comment: @deyore Thanks for all the help. I think the point of the problem was to understand what it is asking rather than try to find a solution.